# Output RadioButtonList from C# to ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to fill a `RadioButtonList` from database and output it in a `ListView`:

What I have tried:

ASP:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" DataSource=<%#Eval("respostas")%>></asp:RadioButtonList>
</ItemTemplate>
```

C#:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["nome_pergunta"] = reader["pergunta"];

DataTable respostas = new DataTable();
respostas.Columns.Add("respostaA", typeof(string));
respostas.Columns.Add("respostaB", typeof(string));
respostas.Columns.Add("respostaC", typeof(string));
respostas.Columns.Add("respostaD", typeof(string));
DataRow linha = respostas.NewRow();
linha["respostaA"] = reader["respostaA"].ToString();
linha["respostaB"] = reader["respostaB"].ToString();
respostas.Rows.Add(linha);


dr["respostas"] = respostas;

dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

I also tried: 
ASP:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("respostas")%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

C#:

```
RadioButtonList respostas = new RadioButtonList();
respostas.ID = "respostas_" + numero_respota;
respostas.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader["respostaA"].ToString(), "a"));
respostas.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader["respostaB"].ToString(), "b"));
respostas.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader["respostaC"].ToString(), "c"));
respostas.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader["respostaD"].ToString(), "d"));
```

None of them worked, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests here is the solution:

ASP:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" DataSource=<%#Eval("respostas")%>></asp:RadioButtonList>
</ItemTemplate>
```

In C#:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add(reader["respostaA"].ToString());
l.Add(reader["respostaB"].ToString());

dr["respostas"] = l;
```